# How to define TS type for [key, val]?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How should I defined TS type for `[key, val]` pair returned from `Object.entries`?

```js
type objType = {
    one: string | null;
    two: string | null;
};

const obj: objType = {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two',
};

Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => {
    console.log(key, val);
});
```

**EDIT: this was just a simplified example. The problem was in my code**

Everything works as expected. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me: if you have ES2017.object installed, you should actually support `Object.entries` and TypeScript is able to infer the types for `key` and `val` respectively. `key` will be typed as `string`, and `val` typed as `string | null`

Comment: You shouldn't. Typescript does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean define the types of the key/value pair of the `.map` parameters like this?

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]: [Type1, Type2]) => {
    console.log(key, val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```js
type objType = {
    [key: string]: string | null;
};

type objEntriesType = objType[];

const obj: objType = {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two',
};

const result: objEntriesType[] = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => {
    console.log(key, val);
});
```